# Calcular las diferencias entre las celdas en las columnas de una dataframe

Tags: r

Tengo un universo de inversión STOXX que proviene [de aquí](https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt):

```
 head(df)

        Date   SX5P   SX5E  SXXP  SXXE  SXXF  SXXA   DK5F  DKXF
1 1986-12-31 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
2 1987-01-01 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
3 1987-01-02 770.89 891.78 82.57 97.80 97.43 69.37 647.62 65.81
4 1987-01-05 771.89 898.33 82.82 98.60 98.19 69.16 649.94 65.82
5 1987-01-06 775.92 902.32 83.28 99.19 98.83 69.50 652.49 66.06
6 1987-01-07 781.21 899.15 83.78 98.96 98.62 70.59 651.97 66.20
```

Para entender los principios de asignación de acciones. Tengo que **determinar, *al final de cada mes*, la asignación de manera que cada acción contribuya con el mismo riesgo a la cartera total.**

Entonces sigo [este tutorial](https://medium.com/python-data/assessing-the-riskiness-of-a-portfolio-with-python-6444c727c474) que le hace para Python.

Pero, por una parte tengo problemas al calcular los retornos diarios. En efecto tengo todos los datos gracias a:

```
url <- 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = ';', skip = 4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')
df$Date <- as.Date(sub('(.{2}).(.{2}).(.{4})', "\\3-\\2-\\1", df$Date))
```

Y después tengo que calcularlos. He visto que [hay una funcion, `Delt`](https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/Delt.html) que dice ser capaz de hacerlo entre dos columnas. Pero tengo que hacer las diferencias entre cada celdas. No sé cómo hacerlo:

```
new = df[2:9]
# ¿Cómo calcular las diferencias?
Delt(df.a_given_day,df.a_given_day_plus_1,k=0:2)  #... Delt lo hace por 0,1 y 2 periodos entre columnas.
```

Tras, podria calcular la covarianza con `cov_matrix_df <- cov(data.matrix(new, rownames.force = NA))` y continuar mi búsqueda para el cálculo del riesgo.

Por otra parte no sé cómo modificarlo para determinar, *al final de cada mes* el riesgo para decidir *al final de cada mes*, la asignación.

#### my attempt:

De [esta respuesta] [4] intenté de esta respuesta:

```
dr_df = cbind(df[-1,1],apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1)))
```

Que devuelve:

```
> head(dr_df)
                  SX5P         SX5E         SXXP         SXXE         SXXF         SXXA
[1,] 6209  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,] 6210 -0.005303226 -0.010035301 -0.002295795 -0.007912355 -0.006424638  0.004488850
[3,] 6213  0.001297202  0.007344861  0.003027734  0.008179959  0.007800472 -0.003027245
[4,] 6214  0.005220951  0.004441575  0.005554214  0.005983773  0.006517975  0.004916136
[5,] 6215  0.006817713 -0.003513166  0.006003842 -0.002318782 -0.002124861  0.015683453
[6,] 6216 -0.004595435 -0.013101262 -0.003103366 -0.011014551 -0.009531535  0.005949851
              DK5F          DKXF
[1,]  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
[2,]  0.0036574404  0.0038133008
[3,]  0.0035823477  0.0001519526
[4,]  0.0039234391  0.0036463081
[5,] -0.0007969471  0.0021192855
[6,] -0.0098164026 -0.0087613293
```

Lo que parece bastante bueno, pero no entiendo el código: / Y cuando intento crear la matriz de covarianza, tengo algunos problemas:

```
> cov(dr_df[2:8])
Error in cov(dr_df[2:8]) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
> cov(dr_df)
             SX5P SX5E SXXP SXXE SXXF SXXA DK5F DKXF
     9886513   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SX5P      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SX5E      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXP      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXE      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXF      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
SXXA      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DK5F      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
DKXF      NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema fundamental es que en el `data.frame` inicial tienes dos filas sin cotizaciones:

```
en_cero <- which(apply(df[,-1],1,function(x) any(x==0)))
df[en_cero, ]

           Date SX5P SX5E SXXP SXXE SXXF SXXA DK5F DKXF
7536 2016-03-25    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
7537 2016-03-28    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Con `apply(df[,-1],1,function(x) any(x==0))` "aplicamos" una función por fila y retornamos TRUE si alguna cotización está en 0.

Para poder generar los "daily returns" es necesario que no existan cotizaciones en 0, ya que al hacer `diff(x)/head(x,-1))` cuando `head(x,-1)` valga 0 se producirá un división por 0 resultando en un valor `Nan` que impiden generar la matriz de covarianza. Podemos borrar estas filas:

```
df2 <- df[-en_cero, ]
```

Luego, tanto la función `Delt` como `apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1))` hacen básicamente lo mismo, calculan el porcentaje de variación de un día a otro, obtienen la diferencia de una celda con la anterior y la dividen por la celda anterior. Lo particular de la formula que has compartido, es que te retornará una fila menos, producto que en el primer día del `data.frame` obviamente no tienes cotización anterior. `Delt` por otro lado te retorna la misma cantidad de filas pero si no me equivoco, la primera son todos valores `NA`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
        cbind(
                Date=df2[-1,1],
                data.frame(apply(df2[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1)))
                )
        )
```

Con lo anterior, generamos un `data.frame` similar al original, le dejamos la fecha a titulo informativo, con una fila menos (de ahí que hacemos `df2[-1,1]`) y con los porcentajes de variación de cada cotización y día. Ahora sí es posible generar la matriz de covarianza, pero obviamente solo podemos utilizar los valores numéricos, por lo que hay que excluir la columna de fecha:

```
cov(df2[, -1])

             SX5P         SX5E         SXXP         SXXE         SXXF         SXXA         DK5F         DKXF
SX5P 0.0001458898 0.0001531675 0.0001339905 0.0001400356 0.0001335696 0.0001283412 0.0001355236 0.0001410957
SX5E 0.0001531675 0.0001781671 0.0001431415 0.0001622366 0.0001519764 0.0001252829 0.0001497803 0.0001561299
SXXP 0.0001339905 0.0001431415 0.0001267415 0.0001328073 0.0001265858 0.0001210988 0.0001314346 0.0001359420
SXXE 0.0001400356 0.0001622366 0.0001328073 0.0001502001 0.0001410354 0.0001165071 0.0001412857 0.0001471070
SXXF 0.0001335696 0.0001519764 0.0001265858 0.0001410354 0.0001343114 0.0001130397 0.0001380515 0.0001432671
SXXA 0.0001283412 0.0001252829 0.0001210988 0.0001165071 0.0001130397 0.0001257977 0.0001221743 0.0001254364
DK5F 0.0001355236 0.0001497803 0.0001314346 0.0001412857 0.0001380515 0.0001221743 0.0001914781 0.0001946354
DKXF 0.0001410957 0.0001561299 0.0001359420 0.0001471070 0.0001432671 0.0001254364 0.0001946354 0.0002103559
```

### Comentario adicional

Un dato más, cuando haces:

```
dr_df = cbind(df[-1,1],apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1)))
cov(dr_df[2:8])
class(dr_df)
[1] "matrix"
```

terminas generando una matriz y no un `data.frame` como podrías suponer, esto hace que cuando intentas acceder las columnas 2 a 8, el resultado no sea el esperado:

```
dr_df[2:8]
[1] 6210 6213 6214 6215 6216 6217 6220
```

Puedes solucionarlo convirtiendo la matriz en un `data.frame`

```
dr_df = data.frame(cbind(df[-1,1],apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) diff(x)/head(x,-1))))
class(dr_df)
[1] "data.frame"
```